# Issue with cultureinfo- add language

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

After searching a lot on internet when I could not get a solution I am here.

I have a requirement in my project which supports multiple languages.
When I am switching to a specific language it works fine if the language is already there in system language preferences, if not it shows an error.
To resolve error I had to go manually to the below location and then add language.

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language >> Add a Language

And everything works as expected.

This is what I want to do programmatically: In code somehow I could add a language to system language preference list.

> (c# - preferred language).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider installing the language during the installation of your software, if it's a desktop application, because adding a new language will require admin rights anyways.

If it's a web page, you will have even more troubles doing so because there will be no installation program.

You might want to make a specific culture mandatory and choose to support a fallback instead.

**Edit**:

For a manual installation that could be automated during your installation procedure, you can find language files on [Microsoft's website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win81):  (pick the "Download Center" version) and follow the [tutorial for unattended windows installation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766278(v=ws.10).aspx) :

if it can be of any use, [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/322417) will show you which rights are required to install a language.

Comment: Luckily Its a windows application. Can you elaborate a bit more how to install a language while installing application.

Comment: if you have a setup program, such as InstallShield you can either add a script to install your language, or even maybe it is supported by the installation builder. it will really depend on what product you use. however, again, you should ask yourself : If I was a user of that application and I decided not to have that culture installed on my computer: Would I really want another software to install it for me behind my back?

Comment: You can find language files here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win81 (pick the "Download Center" version) and follow that tutorial for unattended windows installation : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766278(v=ws.10).aspx. If this works for you, I'll copy it in the Answer